# Error triggers when scraping historical data from stock that only has 1 day of historical data

Tags: python, dataframe

I'm getting data using yahoo_fin. Im Getting the last 100 days from current date. The list tickers_sp500() works but when I try using list tickers_nasdaq(). It keeps throwing timestamp error. I found that it triggers the error when it gets to AGBR from Nasdaq list which only has one row in historical data. In this example Its getting all the data and not just the last 100 but I still get the error.
Error is "KeyError: 'timestamp'"

```
import yahoo_fin.stock_info as si

lists=si.tickers_nasdaq()
#lists=si.tickera_sp500()
prices={}

for ticker in lists:
    prices[ticker]=si.get_data(ticker)

print(prices[ticker])
```

That code works with sp500. So my question is how can I get the code to skip tickers that don't have historical data more than 100 or is there a way to ignore that error so i can still get the data even though it's less than 100 rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ticker data is stored in dictionary-like data structures and those defective tickers (e.g. `AGBR`) may be missing the `timestamp` key of such dictionary, so it's failing to fetch.

You can skip the defective ones by wrapping the `si.get_data` call in a `try..except` clause as explained in the [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions).

In your case, the code would become

```py
...
for ticker in lists:
    try:
        prices[ticker]=si.get_data(ticker)
    except KeyError:
        print(f'Ticker {ticker} missing data')
        pass
```

Comment: @onlypencil Consider accepting the post, if that answers your question.